# Different behaviours for different breeds

Tags: communication, netlogo

This is my first netlogo model and I am facing some difficulties

I have two types of breeds. I want one of them to spread and receive a behavior, and the other one to receive it but do not spread it.
To pass the behavior:

```
to pass
  if any? other turtles-here with [good-deed?]
    [ set good-deed? true ]
end
```

In the model this only passes the behavior between one of the breeds, and I would like the other breeds to receive the behavior, but do not spread it.

Answer (score 2):

So you can setup different breeds with the **breed** command. Just this at the top:

```
breed [spreaders spreader]
breed [non-spreaders non-spreader]
```

and in **go**, only ask the spreaders to perform the **pass** command. Like this:

```
to go
ask turtles [
   move 
   ;; etc. (whatever you want both of them to do)
  ]
ask spreaders[
   pass]

end
```

ps. you might what to change the pass command to:

```
ask other turtles-here with [good-deed? = false][
  set good-deed? true]
```